# Практическое применение префиксного оператора

Tags: операторы, инкремент

Сегодня с коллегой зашёл разговор о префиксных и постфиксных операторах. 
Коллега говорит, что он всегда использовал в жизни постфикс и работает всё корректно, а префикс в принципе не видит смысла в таком случае использоваться.

Понимаю, что в контексте многопоточных приложений это имеет значение, ибо постфикс происходит за три операции, но в целом (и как пример конкретно на *PHP*), есть ли какие-то примеры, когда нужно использоваться префиксный оператор и точка? Где постфикс только собьет и не возможно применить.

---

Вопрос касается как инкремента, так и декремента

Comment: Это можно показать развечто на конкретных примерах. Если например в функцию нужно передать неувеличиное значение, а значение увеличить - то всегда префикс.

Comment: @nick_n_a, в случае, который вы описали, нужен наоборот постфикс. Префикс увеличит значение **до** передачи.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как насчет PHP, а в C++ постфиксный оператор требует больше ресурсов при реализации перегрузки (для нетривиальных типов конечно). Поэтому рекомендуют писать

```
for(i=0;i!=max;++i)
```

Вместо

```
for(i=0;i!=max;i++)
```

Имеется ввиду, что если "i" это целое, то разницы (на большинстве платформ) не будет. Но если это код шаблона, и "i" может быть нетривиальным пользовательским типом с перегруженными операторами постинкремента и прединкремента, то тогда реализация "++i" будет выполнятся быстрее и требовать меньше ресурсов, чем реализация "i++".

UPD1:

К примеру, если понадобился счетчик "i" не простое целое, а BigInteger, то код в примере будет работать. Но перегрузка оператора префиксного инкремента для BigInteger проще по реализации и требует меньше ресурсов, чем перегрузка оператора постфиксного инкремента для BigInteger.

Как-то мне понадобились длинные целые, но GMP использовать было нельзя, так как длинные целые нужны были для микроконтроллера без ОС и без кучи. Пришлось написать свою реализацию BigInteger без использования кучи. В этой реализации, в том числе, перегружены операторы и префиксного инкремента и постфиксного инкремента. И оказалось, что перегрузка оператора префиксного инкремента требует меньше ресурсов, чем перегрузка оператора постфиксного инкремента. Так как для перегрузки оператора постфиксного инкремента нужно сначала сохранить старое значение, а это (как минимум) копирование всех данных в отдельный буфер.

Вот ссылка на проект, если кто интересуется, то можно посмотреть, как сделана перегрузка операторов и почему перегрузка оператора префиксного инкремента требует меньше ресурсов:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/

Comment: Кубик Рубика отдыхает...